# How to interpret/understand ' Aqeem-us-salah'?

Tags: salat, tafseer

It is popularly interpreted as establish the prayer.

But what is the meaning of establish the prayer,
Why god is asking us to establish the prayer, 
Why not he is saying recite/read/perform the prayer 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

In arabic "aqueem" has the meaning of not just establishing the prayer but also:

> [أقام الصَّلاةَ أدامها ، وفَّاها بصورة كاملة](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/home.php?word=%D8%A3%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9%D9%8E&lang_name=ar-ar&type_word=0&dspl=0)

Translation:

> establish the prayer in a complete way.

This means: Doing the prayer at the right time and in the right way.

One could add: conserve it, keep it unchanged and continue with it and make it everlasting!

[Source](http://www.almaany.com/home.php?language=arabic&lang_name=%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A&word=%D8%A3%D9%82%D9%85)

Comment: But the question is concentrated on "[establish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/establish)". Not what's emphasized along with it.

Comment: @Bleeding the question is about 'aqeem'. The translation into english is not just establish. It is establish in a complete way.

Comment: @user689 so the question that should technically be answered is "why not He is saying recite/read/perform the prayer *in a complete way* 5 times"?

Comment: @Bleeding quran is actually saying that- in arabic - it is just the translation that isn't complete.

Answer (score -1):

It's saying to "establish/keep up the system of Islam" one needs to look it up in context of al-Furqan. Surah 2 aya 3